# Android mediaplayer play file wihle writing to file

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I have some mp3 files on a cloud service.The links are like that `https://dns/mp3filename.mp3?dl=1`. I can play the files streaming with Vlc media player and I can write the bytes in files in Java. But when I try to play the links in Android media player some times it plays some times I get error(1,-1004) that is media_error_io.
**Streaming code:**

```
mp.setDataSource(link);
        mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mp.prepareAsync();
        mp.setWakeMode(ctx, PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
        mp.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.start();
            }
        });
```

I have been looking for a library but I could not found one. I just came with the idea about download the file and play it while downloading, but the media player only reads the first bytes I give it to play and called `setOnCompletionListener` even if the file have been completely downloaded.

**That code is in a thread and it's for download the file**

```
try {
        File cacheDir = new File(ctx.getCacheDir().getPath()+"/"+"mp3s");
        cacheDir.mkdir();
        File tempFile = File.createTempFile("mp3" + num, ".mp3", cacheDir);

        BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(tempFile));

        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(lien).openConnection();
        httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
        BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(httpURLConnection.getInputStream());

        byte bytes[] = new byte[1048576];
        int len = 0;
        int nbre = 0;
        int current = 0;
        while ((len = bufferedInputStream.read(bytes))!=-1){
            bufferedOutputStream.write(bytes,0,len);
            bufferedOutputStream.flush();
            nbre+= len;
            current += len;

            onLoadingListener.onLoading(current, httpURLConnection.getContentLength());

            if(nbre >= 524288){
                nbre = 0;
                onReadyListener.onReady(tempFile);
            }
        }

        bufferedOutputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

`onReadyListener.onReady(tempFile);` is callback to start the media player like that.

```
playerMediaDownloader.setOnReadyListener(new PlayerMediaDownloader.OnReadyListener() {
            @Override
            public void onReady(final File file) {
                path = file.getPath();
                try {
                    if(!playing) {
                        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "li ready");
                        mp.setDataSource(file.getPath());
                        mp.prepare();
                        mp.start();
                        Log.d(Player.this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "pos:"+mp.getCurrentPosition());
                        playing = true;
                        for (OnTimeChanged l : onTimeChangeds) {
                            l.onTimeChanged(mp.getCurrentPosition(), mp.getDuration());
                        }
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
```

The media player finished to play the file when it reach the 524288 bytes even if the file has been completely downloaded.

I came with another solution that is set the file file again and play it and it worked but, the sound cut a bit and it is not pretty like that.

```
mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

                int currentPosition = mp.getCurrentPosition();
                mp.reset();
                try {
                    Player.this.mp.setDataSource(path);
                    mp.prepare();
                    mp.seekTo(currentPosition);
                    mp.start();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "fini jwe:"+mp.getCurrentPosition());
            }
        });
```

Do you have a better solution to help me make it works fine please, like playing the file asynchronously?